# 変数の値がgoroutine間で同じになってしまう。

Tags: go, goroutine

初めまして。
現在goを勉強しておりまして、goroutineに関して勉強しています。
以下のようにmapにいくつかstringのキーを入れて、値はboolでフラグ管理しております。
値がtrueの時はsleep処理を入れて、falseのときはsleep無しの処理をしたいと思っております。
しかし、以下実行しますと、mapのキー値がいくつか被ってしまいます。
試しに変数のアドレスを確認すると、同じアドレスになっている場合があるのですが、なぜ同じアドレスになっているのでしょうか？
また、どのようにしたら被らないようにmapに入っている全ての値を出力することができるようになりますでしょうか。

## ソース

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func goroutine(name string) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-sleep:
            fmt.Printf("---------------(sleep)name = %s, name of address = %p\n", name, &name)
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            fmt.Printf("---------------wake up name = %s", name)
        case <-start:
            fmt.Printf("---------------(start)name = %s, name of address = %p\n", name, &name)
        }
    }
}

var sleep chan bool
var start chan bool

func main() {
    sleep = make(chan bool)
    start = make(chan bool)

    names := make(map[string]bool)
    names["a"] = false
    names["b"] = false
    names["c"] = false
    names["d"] = true
    names["e"] = false
    for k, v := range names{
        if v {
            go goroutine(k)
            sleep <- true
        } else {
            go goroutine(k)
            start <- true
        }
    }

    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Second)
}
```

## 出力結果

```
# go run main.go
---------------(start)name = a, name of address = 0xc00006e1c0
---------------(start)name = c, name of address = 0xc0000a2000
---------------(sleep)name = c, name of address = 0xc0000a2000
---------------(start)name = e, name of address = 0xc0000a2020
---------------(start)name = a, name of address = 0xc00006e1c0
---------------wake up name = c
```

Comment: `channel(sleep, start)`を複数の `goroutine` が同時に select していますので(入力待ち)、「早いもの勝ち」の状態になってしまっています。この場合、channel を使う必要はなく、例えば https://play.golang.org/p/GTiqR_shMTJ の様にしても良いかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

`goroutine` 関数の中の `for` は `main` の `time.Sleep(1000 * time.Second)` が終わるまで回り続けるからで
一回目のループで `case <-start:` を通過したら次のループでタイミングによって `case <-start:` か `case <-sleep:` を通ります。

単純に `for` を除けば意図した挙動に近いものになると思いますが、 `d` の時だけ `sleep` したいのであれば ↓ な感じでしょうか。

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func goroutine(name string, isSleep bool) {
    if isSleep {
        fmt.Printf("---------------(sleep)name = %s, name of address = %p\n", name, &name)
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("---------------wake up name = %s\n", name)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("---------------(start)name = %s, name of address = %p\n", name, &name)
    }
}

func main() {
    names := map[string]bool{
        "a": false,
        "b": false,
        "c": false,
        "d": true,
        "e": false,
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // 実行多重度を 2 とする場合
    semaphore := make(chan int, 2)
    for k, v := range names {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(k string, v bool) {
            defer wg.Done()
            semaphore <- 1
            goroutine(k, v)
            <-semaphore
        }(k, v)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```